# StaleElementReferenceException python solving the problem

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using chrome driver to extract data.

I'm stuck at one point: I need to a iterate over an entire list (all elements). The first time it works, and I'm able to download one file.

For the second iteration, it shows up a mistake of StaleElementReferenceException with an element is not attached to the page document.

How should I change my loop to get over this mistake?

Comment: Can you show us what you have now.

Comment: @ScamCast edited! Thank you!

Comment: There is an error in your loop: what is the parameter used for `len`?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE exactly my doubt! I don't know what I should put in?

Comment: I think you're going about the problem in the wrong way. You should maybe use "find_elements_by_xpath" and iterate through that list it outputs.

Comment: @ScamCast I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```py
options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option')
for option in options:
    result = option.click()
    ...
```

See the documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath

Comment: Also the thing is I need to have multiple for loops, because I'm selecting an element within a list, which will open another list, in which I need to select another element and so on

Comment: just tried this, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the issue is that clicking on the options is making more options appear. You could do something like this - make a generator to yield all elements that haven't previously been found, until there are none left that haven't been seen already. (It seems WebElements are not hashable so can't be stored directly in a set but can be identified uniquely by their [`id` attributes](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.id), but you might need to check if this works when new elements are added to the page.)

```
def all_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    found = set()
    while True:
        found_new_ones = False
        for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
            if element.id not in found:
                found_new_ones = True
                found.add(element.id)
                yield element
         if not found_any:
             return

for element in all_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'):
    element.click()
```

Note that this will first click on all elements that were initially on the page, in the order they appear, and only then start clicking on new elements that have appeared after clicking. If you want a different order, or if elements sometimes disappear, you could alter it to search for elements again each time, like this:

```
def all_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    found = set()
    while True:
        for el in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
            if el.id not in found:
                found.add(element.id)
                yield element
                break
        else:
            return
```

Comment: I want to click on one thing, then that will lead to another list, and so on. Why would I want it to click over all elements in the list? Where is that going to take me?

Comment: 'lead to another list' - do you mean on a new page? Or makes another list' appear on the same page?

Comment: Same page for some and after that a new page.

Comment: You need to define in what order you want to iterate through the original and newly appeared elements, or clarify your question, if these solutions aren't what you are looking for